# Problem creating an Entity object/queryable from the result of a LINQ join in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm attempting to write a search function for a database table that needs to access information from related tables using Entity Framework.  However, I'm running into problems getting the data back out of my initial query after doing a join on the parent table and the related tables.  My code currently looks like this.  I initialize my queryable object

```
IQueryable<PurchaseOrder> po = _context.PurchaseOrders;
```

Where PurchaseOrder is an Entity type.  Then there is a series of blocks like this.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchViewModel.Comment)){
     var helper = _context.PurchaseOrderComments.Where(x => x.CommentText.Contains(searchViewModel.Comment));

     var mid = po.Join(helper, r => r.PurchaseOrderID, u => u.PurchaseOrderID, (r, u) =>
                new
                {
                    PurchaseOrderID = r.PurchaseOrderID,
                    PurchaseOrderNumber = r.PurchaseOrderNumber,
                    VendorID = r.VendorID,
                    ContractNumber = r.ContractNumber,
                    BuyerUserID = r.BuyerUserID
                });

     po = mid.Select(x => new PurchaseOrder
            {
                PurchaseOrderID = x.PurchaseOrderID,
                PurchaseOrderNumber = x.PurchaseOrderNumber,
                VendorID = x.VendorID,
                ContractNumber = x.ContractNumber,
                BuyerUserID = x.BuyerUserID
            });
 }
```

After each block, po is passed to the next search parameter.  However, as you might guess, my program complains that I can't build a complex type in mid's Select statement.  I've also tried building PurchaseOrder objects from the contents of mid, inserting them into a new List of PurchaseOrders, and converting that list into a queryable to assign to po to pass on to the next block.  However, that changes po's data type from System.Data.Object.ObjectSet to System.Collections.Generic.List, which then throws an InvalidOperationException the next time I try and iterate through it using a foreach.

So my question is, are there any obvious mistakes in my approach or any suggestions for other ways to approach the problem?  Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Projecting to mapped entity types is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. If I understand what you're trying to do, you should be able to do something like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchViewModel.Comment)){
  po = po.Where(
     o => o.PurchaseOrderComments.Any(
       c => c.CommentText.Contains(searchViewModel.Comment)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

StriplingWarrior's solution is the best way. In case that your `PurchaseOrder` class really doesn't have a navigation collection of `PurchaseOrderComments` (which would force you to use a join) the following should work and is simpler as your double projection:

```
po=po.Join(helper, r => r.PurchaseOrderID, u => u.PurchaseOrderID, (r, u) => r);
```